# ros2 roscd feature

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I do not found an equivalent to roscd in ros2.
Is it implemented ?
Does ament support that feature ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277801/ros2-roscd-feature/) by [Vincent R](https://answers.ros.org/users/85/vincent-r/) on ROS Answers with karma: 365 on 2017-12-11

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While a verb like `cd` can easily be contributed to the `ros2cli` tools the question is what should the semantic of that command be? In ROS 1 when using the devel space it brought you to the source folder of a package. In ROS 2 there is no concept of a devel space and after installing a package there is no correlation to the source space anymore. So the only possible location to switch to would be the install prefix of the package or the location where the package manifest is (in the subfolder `share/<pkgname>` in the install space). I am just not sure how useful that would be...

**Update:**

The `ros2` command is only available after installation and at that time the source code of packages is potentially not available anymore (and also its location is generally not known). Therefore I created a `colcon` specific shell function named `colcon_cd` which only operates on the filesystem and doesn't utilize any installed ROS workspace. The PR for this functionality is here: https://github.com/colcon/colcon-cd/pull/1 Please feel free to comment / provide feedback on how it works for you - I am probably not a good tested of this functionality since I have never used `roscd` in the first place.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2017-12-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It has not been implemented yet. It is likely that we will implement a command like that since many people find it useful. The underlying capabilities are definitely available from ament. (Try `src/ament/ament_tools/scripts/ament.py list_packages ./src`)

A contribution of a verb `cd` for the `ros2` command would be appreciated. This is probably an easy way to get involved if anyone is interested.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-12-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vincent R](https://answers.ros.org/users/85/vincent-r/) on 2018-01-10**:
I will see what I can do and if it makes sense to do it.

**Comment by [Georg Bartels](https://answers.ros.org/users/2542/georg-bartels/) on 2019-09-05**:
Any news on this feature? I couldn't find it as a verb of the ros2 command.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2019-09-05**:
Please read the accepted answer which describes why such a command isn't implemented.

**Comment by [Georg Bartels](https://answers.ros.org/users/2542/georg-bartels/) on 2019-09-16**:
Thank you for the answer! From the accepted answer it was not 100% clear to me whether this verb was in the development cue or not. Now, it is. Still, after developing with ROS2 for a couple of weeks I still miss such a verb to quickly navigate to source packages that I have checked out in an overlay. I liked that in ROS1, and some of my colleagues share the impression...

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2019-09-16**:
If https://github.com/colcon/colcon-core/issues/139 gets implemented it would be possible to provide a function which goes to the source directory of the package within the same workspace (basically `colcon list --packages-select <PKGNAME> --paths-only` if it returns exactly one path).

**Comment by [Georg Bartels](https://answers.ros.org/users/2542/georg-bartels/) on 2019-09-17**:
That would be great! I'll make sure to watch that issue. :)